# Как сделать выравнивание в FrameworkElementFactory?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Так не работает выравнивание:

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();

FrameworkElementFactory gr = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
gr.SetValue(Grid.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

FrameworkElementFactory wp = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(WrapPanel));
wp.SetValue(WrapPanel.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, i.Name);//добавим текст


wp.AppendChild(tb);

gr.AppendChild(wp);

template.VisualTree = gr;

button.ContentTemplate = template;
```

Comment: Что означает «не работает»? Покажите полный пример.

Comment: А зачем вам нужно в `Grid` размещать `WrapPanel`, если у вас нет других элементов в гриде и вы его не разделяете на столбцы или строки?

Comment: есть и другие. просто они здесь пропущены. разделение планируется